# How to copy files using Ant between two computers with a low speed of connection?

Tags: java, ant, build, copy

I had two computers that are located in different parts of the world (Russia and USA) and I need to copy many (100+) small files from one machine to another with Ant. I use usual approach:

```
<copy preservelastmodified="true" todir="${todir}">
    <fileset dir="${fromdir}" />
</copy>
```

It doesn't work because during the copying task some files are missed.

Missed files are always random. Sometimes all files are copied just fine and sometimes some of them are missing. I suppose it depends on connection speed and latency.

Remote directory are mapped using NIS and copying task is been executing on Solaris (if it's matter). Is there any Ant task or special approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Which files are missing? Is some determined extension? Do you have the remote directory mapped on you build machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try putting the 100+ small files into a single Zip or Jar and transmitting that one archive.

Comment: I has clean forgotten it. Thank you!